# Martingale and finite stopping time

Tags: martingales, stopping-times

Let $(X_n, \mathcal F_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a martingale and $\tau$ be a a.s. finite stopping time and  $\mathbb{E}(|X_\tau|) < \infty$. Could someone provide me an example where $\lim \inf\mathbb{E}(1_{\tau\geq n} |X_n|) \neq 0$? I struggle to wrap my head around the idea that the indicator function does not necessarily become zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice example to know.   **The original "martingale"**: keep doubling your bet until you win.

I bet on a sequence of independent tosses of a fair coin.  At time $n$ I bet $2^n$, so that when the coin is H, my fortune increases by $2^n$ but when the coin is T, my fortune decreases by $2^n$.  [I have unlimited funds to bet, and the casino never closes.]
This is the martincale $X_n$.  So:
$$
X_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \epsilon_k 2^k
$$
where the random signs $\epsilon_k$ are $+1$ or $-1$ independently with probability $1/2$ for each.  And of course $\mathcal F_n = \sigma\{\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n\}$ has $2^{n+1}$ atoms of probability $2^{-n-1}$.

Then let
$$
\tau = \inf\{n : X_n > 0\} = \inf\{n : \epsilon_n = +1\} .
$$
Things to check:

$\tau$ is a stopping time,
$[\tau = n\} = \{\epsilon_k=-1\text{ for }0 \le k \le n-1\text{ and }\epsilon_n = 1\}$,
$\tau < \infty$ a.s.,
$X_\tau = 1$ a.s.,
$\{\tau \ge n\} = \{\epsilon_k=-1\text{ for }0 \le k \le n-1\}$,
$$
\mathbb P[\mathbf1_{\tau\ge n} X_n = 0] = 1-2^{-n}
\\
\mathbb P[\mathbf1_{\tau\ge n} X_n = 1] = 2^{-n-1}
\\
\mathbb P[\mathbf1_{\tau\ge n} X_n = -2^{n+1}-1] = 2^{-n-1}
$$
So that
$$
\mathbb E\big[\mathbf1_{\tau\ge n} |X_n|\big] = 1\cdot2^{-n-1} +(2^{n+1}-1)) \cdot2^{-n-1} = 1 .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another example is the simple symmetric random walk with $X_0=0$ and  $\tau=\inf\{n: X_n=1\}$. Because $X$ stopped at time $\tau$ is still  a martingale, you have
$$
0=\Bbb E[X_{n\wedge\tau}]=\Bbb E[X_n; n<\tau]+\Bbb P[n\ge \tau].
$$
And because $X_n\le 0$ for $n<\tau$, this leads to
$$
\Bbb P[\tau\le n]=\Bbb E[|X_n|; n<\tau].
$$
The left side converges to $1$ as $n\to\infty$.